# pcs status is reporting wrong output in Corosync and pacemaker configuration

Tags: centos, pacemaker, corosync

I've configured Corosync and Pacemaker in two Centos servers and everything is working fine.

The problem is when I issue

```
pcs status
```

It reports:

```
Online: [ Node1.localomain ]
OFFLINE: [ Node2.localdomain ]

Full list of resources:

 VIP    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started Node1.localomain
 haproxyLB  (ocf::heartbeat:haproxy):   Started Node2.localomain
```

Which is exactly the reverse in reality!

Node1.localomain is the hostname of node1 and Node2.localomain is the hostname if node 2.

In fact Node2.localomain has taken the VIP and is serving requests but as you see pcs is reporting that VIP is started in Node1.localdomain and Node2.localdomain is offline!!

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Could you add the corosync configuration? I would suspect that you most likely have the nodes switched up in the corosync configuration, DNS or, /etc/hosts.

Comment: Sorry I was so busy for the pas weeks. Emmm, hosts seems to be a good suggestion, I'll check that out. My Corosync configuration is based on IP addresses. I'll either come back with my configuration sample or a thanks note in the case of solving by /etc/hosts

Comment: @Dok sorry to update so late. You were totally right! It was all about hosts file miss configuration! Thank you for the suggestion